# Can an application started with ltsp-localapps write data to a local storage device (i.e a LOCALDEV as defined in lts.conf)?

Tags: 12.04, ltsp, motion

I run successfully:

```
ltsp-localapps motion
```

I can write the output onto the ltsp-sever's disk, but I am not able to write the output files to a local device on the ltsp-client (e. g. SD card, local hard drive, pen stick) which gets automatically mounted to `/media/(user-name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: Yes! It is possible.

Long: When running

```
user@server:~$ ltsp-localapps application
```

then `application` is started for `user` on the thin-client and not on `server`, `/home/user` is mounted on the thin-client using `fuse.sshfs` (rw).

The important thing is to make the local storage device accessible (rw) to `user`.
In case of a `vfat` device a line in `/etc/fstab` (of the ltsp-thin-client)

```
/dev/disk/by-label/UUI /media/ vfat uid=1000,umask=0022 0 0
```

accomplished this task.
This sets `uid=1000` to the "first" user to use a localapp on this thin-client session (the ltsp system dynamically creates UID:GID 1000:1000 for `user`)
and `umask=002`2 sets `chmod 0644` (`rw-r--r--`) and dirs to `0755` (`rwxr-xr-x`).
For the localapp `application` the local storage device is accessible as `/media/`.

If you want to make it persistent, you will have to make the changes to your `lts.conf` - there is a parameter which allows for `fstab` lines called `FSTAB_0..FSTAB_9           string, default unset`

I found it interesting, that the external device is now usable on the server and the client simultaneously.

My intention: to use a localapp on a local storage device for certain tasks is to reduce network traffic and server CPU usage.